# Flutter localization doesn't reload after updating language

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-provider, l10n.js

I am working on localization.The problem is **locale variable in my provider class is actually updated** across the app but the **actual locale of the app is not updated.** I have tried following the documents again.Still doesn't work. I have provided the required codes.

**Provider class**

```
class LocaleProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
 Locale _locale=const Locale('en');
  
  Locale get locale => _locale;

  void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    if (!L10n.all.contains(locale)) return;
    
    _locale = locale;
    print(_locale.toString());
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Updating Language**

```
Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Row(
                children:  [
                  const ButtonBack(), //back button
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    AppLocalizations.of(context)?.language??'Language', //appbar title
                    style: titleStyle,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                 Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context,listen: false)
                    .setLocale(const Locale('my'));
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'မြန်မာ', //burmese language
                      style: styleText,
                    ),
                    (Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context).locale ==
                            const Locale('my'))
                        ? const Icon(Icons.check_outlined)
                        : const SizedBox(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context,listen: false)
                    .setLocale(const Locale('en'));
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      'English', //english language
                      style: styleText,
                    ),
                    (Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context).locale ==
                            const Locale('en'))
                        ? const Icon(Icons.check_outlined)
                        : const SizedBox(), //correct icon for selected language
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

**Main class**

```
builder: (context, child) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
    
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xffFCFCFC),
            ),
            locale: Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context,listen: true).locale,
            supportedLocales: L10n.all,
            localizationsDelegates: const [
              AppLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            home: const HomeMapPage(),
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

for people who experienced this issue further.
just wrap your MaterialApp inside ChangeNotifierProvider.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => LocaleProvider(),
          builder: (context, child) {
            final localeProvider = Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context);
return MaterialApp(locale:localeProvider.locale);});
```